# CSS 100% height with sidebar and content (divs within)

Tags: css, height

I've asked this question before and got a solution but as I work my way into it, I found out that the solution wasn't the best (the suggestion was to set both into display:table-cell)

As I add in divs within, the height changes and the layout gets out of hand.

what I want is really simple, something like the image shown

**[EDIT : this is the main reason why i'm having problem, i'm trying to add a div to include a shadow ]**
 [image]

I want the textured BG to stretch all the way, as tall as how the page would be (so as the content varies the textured bg would follow)

So I made something such as

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="sidecolumn">
<div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
<div id="maincolumn">
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

by setting all the divs and body style to have height:100%; but the problem is that as my content stretches beyond the page limits (a scroll bar appears) the textured BG doesn't flow over, it just stop at where it was. Say the screen is of 800px tall, if the content goes beyond and reaches 1000px, the textured bg stops at 800px.

As I tried what was recommended for me by using display:table-cell, the textured bg flows with the content, but I can't add in my side bar because when I do, there will be a blank space above the content div. Any suggestion on how I should handle this problem?

Comment: you can use css 3 declaration background-size
`background-size:100% 100%;`

Comment: Do you have a fiddle, where `display: table-cell` produces the blank space? Maybe we can fix this.

Comment: yes i've tried, it has to do with the display: table-cell property because i did a perfectly fine layout until the content stretches that i discover the background doesn't go all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Using Xun Yang's approach would work. It's just, as he put it himself, unconventional ;)

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nu2wH/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%:
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  
}

#page {
    background: #444444;
    min-height: 100%; 
    height:auto !important; 
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Social_icons-google-22x22.png?uselang=de") repeat;
}

#sidecolumn  {
    width: 45%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    float: left;
}   

#sidebar {
    background: #ddd;
}
#maincolumn  {
    padding: 5%;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
    background: #AA9933;
    height: 100%:
}    
#content {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

​

Comment: woah! that is kinda how it should look like but i was expecting the background to flow instead of using positions (not very good with them) but it might work :) I'm still looking for a background that flows tho.

Comment: Now I understand what you're up to ;)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use the css 3 declaration background-size, for all browsers

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; //fallback for unsupported browsers and sets the background image
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: problem is it is a textured BG that suppose to repeat itself.

Comment: you can of course change the declaration to repeat, and  remove the positioning, but if its a set texture that only needs to repeat itself, why isn't the regular repeat declaration sufficient

Comment: exactly what i am trying to figure out, it just doesn't flow as large as it should be. the textured bg just stopped at my browser's height, and when the content stretches the height, the texture bg wouldn't follow :( that is if the content overflows to more than the browser's height.

Answer (score 0):

```
#page
{
background:url(images/bg.png);
width:200px;/*Width of your sidebar*/
}
#maincolumn
{
margin-left:200px;/*width of your sidebar*/
}
```

Not very conventional but works :)

Comment: does it go all the way too :o ? i'll give it a try :P